# Passing variable number of arguments to a function within a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments

I want to use **kwargs to pass variable arguments to a function inside a function. It prints as if they are passing, but when I check the file the arguments are written to, they didn't pass at all.

```
from radmc3dPy import *
analyze.writeDefaultParfile('ppdisk')

def problemparams(**kwargs):
      if kwargs is not None:
           for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setup.problemSetupDust('ppdisk', "%s = %s" %(key, value))
```

The function "setup.problemSetupDust()" should pass the key and its value to an .inp file as sets of parameters. However, when I check the file, the values haven't been changed by this method.

Comment: If you don't pass any keyword arguments, `kwargs` will be `{}`, not `None`.

Comment: It looks like youre using [`setup.problemSetupDust`](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~juhasz/radmc3dPyDoc/radmc3dPy.html#radmc3dPy.setup.problemSetupDust) incorrectly.  The first two arguments should be the `model` and `binary`.  Those don't seem to be what you're passing.

Comment: That seems more of a problem of ``setup.problemSetupDust`` not working as you expect, rather than of passing along arguments. After all, the function call seems to work fine.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `setup.problemSetupDust` works fine, if it were getting the arguments then the .inp file would change. When I run it just from the command line there are no issues.

Comment: @Torrance There is no way you can call a function *without* it getting the arguments. Either ``kwargs`` is empty, in which case you never call ``setup.problemSetupDust``, or ``kwargs`` is not empty, in which case ``setup.problemSetupDust`` gets the arguments.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I call `problemparams(tstar=[8511])` which should change the value for tstar in the .inp file. When I include `print(key)` and `print(value)` in the function, tstar and [8511] print, so I know the values are being passed to the function that I wrote. However, they are not being changed in the .inp file, so they must not be being passed to `setup.problemSetupDust()`.

Comment: @Torrance Claiming Python handles call parameters non-deterministic is a pretty strong claim when you are passing a string as the ``binary`` parameter, which expects a boolean. According to the docs, you probably should only call ``setup.problemSetupDust('ppdisk', **kwargs)`` and remove the ``if`` check and ``for`` loop.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you! That's exactly what I needed!!! Sorrry, I'm still a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setup.problemSetupDust` call](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~juhasz/radmc3dPyDoc/radmc3dPy.html#radmc3dPy.setup.problemSetupDust) expects all parameters to be passed as keyword arguments. The correct way to forward these is just

```
def problemparams(**kwargs):
    setup.problemSetupDust('ppdisk', **kwargs)
```